Modify userform's caption by code without trust center permission
I need to change the captions of buttons (or other controls) in an Excel UserForm by code. However, I want to avoid enabling the "Trust access to the VBA project object model" option due to security concerns. Is there an alternative approach or workaround that doesn't require enabling this option?
UserForm1.CommandButton1.Caption = "New Caption"

Thank you for your suggestions.

What happened when you tried that?

Do you need to update the form permanently, or just at runtime?

I want to avoid enabling the "Trust access to the VBA project object model" I belive you are getting that because userform1 is not loaded? You are changing the caption of the control in design time from a module or another form?

I need to change captions based on the selected language at runtime. I have some lists in a worksheet. If I don't enable the "Trust access to the VBA project object model" option, the subroutine in my macro can't change captions.

Here is the principle how you can do it.
It is only the idea!
If you have your languages like:

(First row == language number, First Col language string number)
First in all your userforms give the controls you want to change a tag with the corresponding number.
In every userform have something like that:
Option Explicit
Dim Activated As Boolean

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
Dim g As Control
If Activated Then Exit Sub
Activated = True
For Each g In Me.Controls
    If g.Tag <> "" Then
        g.Caption = GiveMeCaption(Val(g.tag))
    End If
Next g
End Sub
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Activated = False
End Sub

And in a common module something like
Option Explicit
Public LanguageNumber As Long ' you can set this at program start to the number you need
Public Function GiveMeCaption(CaptionNumber)
' Here a code to get the string like
' Row = WorksheetFunction.Match(TheRange, CaptionNumber, True)
' GiveMeCaption = TheRange.cells(row,LanguageNumber+2)
End Function

I leave it to you to write this function to your situation.
It would be better to load the language into a multidimensional array on start and get the language from there, but again, this is only the idea how to handle multiple languages. You may use this also for messages etc...
And a bit of error handling would also be recommended :-)

Similar approach with a bit more detail here: https://worksheetsvba.com/en/create-multilingual-userform
